# Auth0 - get provider user id

Tags: facebook, twitter, auth0

at the moment I am relying on a junky method to get the provider user id (the string/number used in in user page urls of the social) based on splitting the profile "sub" field given from the /profile endpoint.

I saw that the old API had a field named "identities" where seems to be stored the provider user id, is there an equivalent for the new API?

Basically it should return:

- facebook: the user number or url nickname http://www.facebook.com/**mattiamanzati** or http://www.facebook.com/**100011120071734** if a nickname was'nt set
- twitter: the twitter handle http://www.twitter.com/**mattiamanzati**
- instagram: the instagram handle http://www.instagram.com/**cenaacorte**

This is the code I've been using now, and you can see how junky is the provider and provider_uid setting is.

```
var webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
  domain: "himy.eu.auth0.com",
  clientID: "0gz79WpxVxXNH5qeYRXXTxTQiWZZEV9S",
  redirectUri: window.location.href,
  audience: "https://himy.eu.auth0.com/userinfo",
  responseType: "token id_token",
  scope: "openid profile"
});

function handleAuthentication() {
  webAuth.parseHash(function(err, authResult) {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
      window.location.hash = "";
      webAuth.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(err, profile) {
        if (profile) {
          if (window.postMessage) {
            if (profile.sub.indexOf("facebook") === 0) {
              profile.provider_uid = profile.sub.split("|")[1];
              profile.provider = "facebook";
            } else if (profile.sub.indexOf("instagram") === 0) {
              profile.provider_uid = profile.nickname;
              profile.provider = "instagram";
            }
            window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(profile));
          }
          console.log(profile);
        }
      });
    } else if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  if (!window.location.hash) {
    webAuth.authorize();
  } else {
    handleAuthentication();
  }
});
```

Comment: You should only use the user id you get from the APIs to identify users. Facebook does not allow any access to the username field via API any more.

Comment: I needed it not to identify the user, but to open the user social profile when the user profile get clicked.

Comment: Well then use the appropriate properties ... for Facebook that would be the `link` field of the user object.

Comment: Is there any docs about that? I did'nt get it out of the profile object, does it need any additional scope?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ You need to ask for the fields you want since Graph API v2.4, not sure if Auth0 does that. Check their documentation if you need more info on that.